# IntelliJ IDEA + Play!-plugin: Do not open UI Designer for Java source

Tags: java, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0, gui-designer

Running the Community Edition of IntelliJ IDEA on Arch Linux (12.0.4 Build 123.169), I installed the [Play!-2.0 Plugin](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin?pluginId=7080). Once i managed to get it running, I began hitting this wall: whenever I open a *.java-source-file from the project-explorer, it switches me to the UI Designer-view, and I can't access my source code anymore - it just keeps telling me that the "Form file is invalid: Not IntelliJ IDEA GUI Designer form file".

The files I want to work on are pure Java-code, so I have no need for the UI Designer, there is no SWING involved.

Is there a setting somewhere to **not** invoke this view for any files?

*Note: the weird thing is it works if I disable the Play-plugin - something in the plugins.xml maybe?*

Comment: Have you tried to invalidate all IntelliJ caches?

Comment: This should not happen, try [running with the default settings](http://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23358108), probably there is something wrong with the file type associations.